# magento 2 - how to set allow countries for shipping for website

Tags: magento2, shipping

I cannot find Allow Countries for Shipping in my admin panel on store view level configuration

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you override database core_config_data table it works. You can define "stores" as scope - website id - and country codes

[image]

Comment: Can we get allowedCountries by storeviews programmatically later? I tried to get allowedCountries, but it seems it only gets allowed countries by website, not storeviews.

Comment: have you try using website in scope column?

Comment: yes, i tried. `$allowedCountries = $this->allowedCountries->getAllowedCountries("default",0);` this code is working, and it returns the allowed countries for default website. but this code `$allowedCountries = $this->allowedCountries->getAllowedCountries("stores",12);` doesn't return allowed countried for storeview, it gives a error. `"invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/websites/public/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/AllowedCountries.php on line 66"`

Comment: do you have a column in table with scope "stores" and "scope_id" 12? can you open a new question post and send me link please?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/285985/26668

Comment: I have created a new question for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Shipping adjustments can only be done on "Website" level and this is something that cannot be achieved on "store view" level.

Store views change the way pages are presented, and are typically used to display a store with different layouts or languages.

Website is the top-level container for sites, shipping methods, payment methods, and so on. To create completely separate sites that do not share cart, shipping methods, and so on, you must create separate websites.

Store is contained by a website . In turn, a store contains at least one store view.

Multiple stores can share cart, user sessions, payment gateways, and so on, but they have separate catalog structures.

Follow this link for more information:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html

Comment: is it possible? in mage 1 is possible to do it

Comment: Not sure who down-voted, however, that will still not change the fact that changing allowed counties list as per store view is not possible.

Comment: there is not a way to set allow countries for shipping for website?

Comment: You need to change the store view to website ;) Top left corner

Comment: Take a look at this, it might help you achieve what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516494/set-allowed-countries-on-store-view

Comment: yes just see this post i will try thanks a lot

Comment: Great, I hope I helped ;)