# Magento 2.3.1 Get Allowed Countries by storeview

Tags: magento2, database, admin, store-view

It seems in Magento 2, we can only configure **Allowed Countries** per *WEBSITE* or *STORE*. but not STOREVIEWS.

[image: Magento country options]

I found this solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/245401/26668, where we can add **Allowed Countries** to *STOREVIEW* directly to the table `core_config_data`

[image: Magento 2 STOREVIEW database]

The problem is, it doesn't seem that I can get the Allowed Countries programmatically.

I have tried following,

```
use Magento\Directory\Model\AllowedCountries;

public function __construct(
    AllowedCountries $allowedCountries
)
{
    $this->allowedCountries = $allowedCountries;
}

 $allowedCountries = $this->allowedCountries->getAllowedCountries("default",0);
```

Which works fine, and it returns allowed countries for default website to me.

but if I want to get allowed countries of a specific storeview that has store ID 12, for example,

```
$allowedCountries = $this->allowedCountries->getAllowedCountries("stores",12);
```

it gives me an error.

```
"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/websites/public/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/AllowedCountries.php on line 66"
```

Any ideas on how to get allowed countries by store view?

Comment: do you have a column in table core_config_data with scope "stores" and "scope_id" 12 and "path" gener/country/allow as in  this solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/245401/26668 ?

Comment: yes, i have those columns. I have add a screenshot to the question. please have a look.

Comment: I found the problem. I must write ScopeCode with [ ], so it has to be, `$allowedCountries = $this->allowedCountries->getAllowedCountries("stores",[12]);
`

Comment: great write your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out, I must use array for store Ids, so I need to write Store Ids in [], as following

```
$allowedCountries = $this->allowedCountries->getAllowedCountries("stores",[12]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this link: https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-restrict-specific-us-states-in-checkout-magento-2/